# In OpenGL's glVertexPointer (when using VBO's) why not just set its last parameter to zero?

Tags: opengl, vbo

In OpenGL, when using VBO's, why do I often see the last parameter (the pointer to the data) specified as follows...

```
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (char *) NULL );
```

...instead of simply like this...

```
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

It may just be a question of preferred syntax as it appears to work both ways. But if there's a reason not to just use zero, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it clear (to the reader) that it's a pointer.

There are lots of parameters to openGL calls, which are often zero, so it just makes it a little clearer to read if there are 3 or  4 zeros in a row

Answer (score 2):

> But if there's a reason not to just use zero, why is that?

Lack of understanding of the C programming language. In C the null pointer is `0`, the underlying macro is

```
#define NULL 0
```

there's no typecast there.

Also it's undefined what happens if you cast some number (that's not the result of casting a pointer to intptr_t) to a pointer. Effectively you're cheating the compiler. I explained the details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284829/524368