# OpenGL glMultiDrawElements crashes on index offset vector

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

I have a really tough time coming up with a good title for this question, so please propose a new one if you can come up with a good one. Perhaps we can do it after solving my problem... Now to it:

I am currently porting code to use glMultiDrawElements instead of several calls to glDrawElements. For this, I am using something I call sequenceList, which is just a std::pair of two vectors, one unsigned int and one int.

```
  // Sequence of vectors defining < StartIndex per primitive, Number of vertices per primitive >
  using SequenceList = std::pair< std::vector< unsigned int >, std::vector< GLsizei > >;
```

To be able to use only one draw function for all variants (ever though there is just one primitive to draw using one index list) I've generalized the function call to *always* use a sequenceList object, but with only one index value. This means that I use glMultiDrawElements for all indexed draw calls (and glMultiDrawArrays for non-indexed draw calls).

```
void GLVBOProbe::draw( unsigned startIndex, int numberOfIndicesToDraw ) const
{
  VertexArray::SequenceList sequences = { { startIndex }, { numberOfIndicesToDraw } ) };
  GLVBOLib::the().draw( name_, sequences );
}
```

The draw call then binds the array/normal/texture and index (if needed) buffers. The call to glMultiDrawElements then looks like

```
glMultiDrawElements( info.mode, sequences.second.data(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const GLvoid **)sequences.first.data(), (GLsizei)sequences.second.size() );
```

In my test case, I am rendering 75000 indices starting at 0. So the sequences.second contains 75000 values, and sequences.first contains only one value: 0.

Now to the problem: This crashes with a

```
First-chance exception at 0x000000004735E56B in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

I have tried to find the problem in many different ways, and have finally been able to find a variant that doesn't crash, and the variant baffles me.

If I copy the vector to a new local variable, it works. Since the vector is of size 1, it wouldn't be a problem to just to that, but it feels less fun to do it every frame for 3000 index offsets.

```
// Non crashing version
std::vector< unsigned int > indicesOffset = sequences.first;
// using sequence and indices
glMultiDrawElements( info.mode, sequences.second.data(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const GLvoid **)indicesOffset.data(), (GLsizei)sequences.second.size() );
```

A colleague of mine says it might have to do with the memory alignment of the vector, saying I have to use boost's boost::aligned_allocator to get it to work.

Comment: and if you use a reference? `std::vector< unsigned int >& indicesOffset = sequences.first;`

Comment: It might have something to do with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719287/using-glmultidrawelements-in-64bit-os
and the fact that it doesn't crash when copying the vector is purely coincidental. It's just because there is nothing in the memory _after_ the newly created vector.
Instead of having a vector of ints, I should have a vector of int pointers.

Comment: are you one 64 bit? if so then I can indeed see the problem with the cast to `GLVoid**` from `unsigned int*`

Comment: Yes, I'm on 64 bit. I also think that this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(GLvoid*)` is not guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof(unsigned int)`. You can however replace `unsigned int` with `GLintptr​` which is guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer.

Comment: Thank you, the GLintptr is also an alternative:https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182391-How-to-use-glMultiDrawElements-and-glDrawElements

Comment: Wait.. a GLVoid* must be the same size as a (unsigned int*), pointers are always the same size on a platform, aren't they?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your answer as (unsigned int*) and not (unsigned int). My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that I am on a 64 bit platform, and glMultiDrawArrays expect *pointers to `int`s*, not actual `int`s.

More is described here.

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182391-How-to-use-glMultiDrawElements-and-glDrawElements

A solution to this is to use `GLintptr` as the type, which describes a **byte offset** in the array. So each position in the array also have to have it's pointer size multiplied with itself.