# glEnableVertexAttribArray gives invalid operation

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I'm trying to go through the ArcSynthesis tutorials on OS X, and I'm getting the OpenGL error "Invalid Operation" after calling glEnableVertexAttribArray.  I've checked that I do have a VBO bound, per the discussion at [glEnableClientState and glEnableVertexAttribArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827926/glenableclientstate-and-glenablevertexattribarray), and am not sure what to check next.

I'm using OS X 10.8, the OpenGL 3.2 profile, and Xcode 4.6.

I'm trying to write a class that will load in the XML model files used in the tutorials, and I *think* that I'm doing the same operations in the same order as an earlier program that draws a coded-in model.  But I must be doing something different or wrong somehow, and can't figure out what.  Referring to the OpenGL 3.2 documentation says that you get an invalid operation by sending in an index value over the maximum allowed by the OpenGL implementation, but I'm using 0 and 1, which I've used before.

Here's the code, with all the OpenGL error checking edited out for clarity:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    for (int iAttribLoop = 0; iAttribLoop < [attributeAnalyzers count]; iAttribLoop++) {
        AttributeAnalyzer *theAnalyzer = [attributeAnalyzers objectAtIndex:iAttribLoop];
        GLuint theIndex = [theAnalyzer index];
        NSLog(@"theIndex is %d", theIndex);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(theIndex);
        glVertexAttribPointer(theIndex, [theAnalyzer size], theType, GL_FALSE, 0, dataOffset);
        dataOffset += sizeof(theType)*[theAnalyzer size]*[theAnalyzer vertexCount];
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Referring to the OpenGL 3.2 documentation says that you get an invalid operation by sending in an index value over the maximum allowed by the OpenGL implementation

No it doesn't. Doing that gives you `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is given by `glEnableVertexAttribArray` only [when you call it and no VAO is bound](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnableVertexAttribArray#Errors).

So you should probably do that.

Comment: That was the hint I needed!  It turns out I was getting bitten by multi-threading--the drawing routine was unbinding the VAO before the method building the VAO finished.  The drawing routine doesn't need to mess with the VAO in this program, so I got rid of that line and fixed things.  Looks like I'll have to study up on threading as well as OpenGL... Thanks!