# glVertexAttribPointer last attribute value or pointer

Tags: pointers, opengl, dr-memory

The last attribute of glVertexAttribPointer is of type const GLvoid*. But is it really a pointer? It is actually an offset. If I put 0, it means an offset of 0 and not a null pointer to an offset. In my engine, I use this function:

```
void AbstractVertexData::vertexAttribPtr(int layout) const
{
    glVertexAttribPointer(layout,
                          getShaderAttribs()[layout]->nbComponents,
                          static_cast<GLenum>(getShaderAttribs()[layout]->attribDataType),
                          getShaderAttribs()[layout]->shouldNormalize,
                          getVertexStride(layout),
                          reinterpret_cast<const void*>(getVertexAttribStart(layout)));
}
```

getVertexAttribStart returns an intptr_t. When I run drmemory, it says "uninitialized read" and I want to remove that warning. This warning comes from the reinterpret_cast. I can't static_cast to a const void* since my value isn't a pointer. What should I do to fix this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Originally, back in OpenGL-1.1 when vertex arrays got introduces, functions like `glVertexPointer`, `glTexCoordPointer` and so on were accepting pointers into client address space. When shaders got introduced they came with arbitrary vertex attributes and the function `glVertexAttribPointer` follows the same semantics (this was in OpenGL-2.1).

The buffer objects API was then reusing existing functions, where you'd pass an integer for a pointer parameter.

OpenGL-3.3 core eventually made the use of buffer objects mandatory and ever since the glVertexAttribPointer functions being defines with a `void*` in their function signature are a sore spot; I've written in extent about it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284829/524368 (but make sure to read the rest of the answers as well).

Eventually new functions got introduced that allow for a more fine grained control over how vertex attributes are accessed, replacing glVertexAttribPointer, and those operate purely on offsets.

Comment: Hmmm okay but it doesn't get rid of the drmemory's warning. I didn't try to replace the function declaration because it's kinda too complicated for me... (messing with OpenGL and GLEW's functions). I just want a cast that doesn't throw warning or another OpenGL function: you said there were gl...Offset functions. What are they?

Comment: @user2924010: gl…Offset are not officially specified. Essentially they're just function pointers with a slightly different signature (taking a `uintptr_t` instead of a `void*`) and assigning the gl…Pointer function addresses to these …Offset pointers. See the very last 3 paragraphs in my other answer to see how it's done. Of course if you want to limit yourself to OpenGL-4 you can use the glVertexAttribFormat family of functions.

Comment: typedef void (*TFPTR_VertexOffset)(GLuint, GLint, GLenum, GLboolean, GLsizei, uintptr_t);
TFPTR_VertexOffset myglVertexAttribOffset = (TFPTR_VertexOffset)glVertexAttribPointer;

This gives an error. It doesn't any information even in debug.

Comment: @user2924010: Which error does it give you exactly?